# Is it possible to build custom Modules in with Dash, similar UI/FE that we can build with JS frameworks? Specifically Dash with React/ Js frameworks?

Tags: python, reactjs, react-native, plotly, plotly-dash

Im trying to build an application with DASH.
Is it possible to build modules with react and use or combine in an Dash application.
I can see Dash have so many issues with its own components and the community is low. But we are pretty happy with the how fast we can built something in Dash using Python Flask.
So if any issues with Dash components, we can choose to go with building/using components with react. Please help me answering this

Also wondering how scalable would be Dash if we consider the present application grows into an enterprise / bigger version?

Is there any performance issues with Dash Front end?

Comment: See the linked answer for the custom module / React question. That is definitely possible. I've done that recently in a previous project at a company.

Comment: I think the second question will probably be less well received on StackOverflow, because it is difficult to quantify 'scalability', 'bigger', 'enterprise' and to give a clear-cut answer. I recommend looking through the threads on the [plotly](https://community.plotly.com/) forum. Search for 'scalability' or something similar and if those aren't satisfying you could create your own thread. The people on there are a lot more likely to answer these kinds of question than on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Bas van der Linden, Thank you for the details. So if i wanted to add more than one components, i should just proceed with same commands in dash-component-boilerplate right?. Basically my application should be generated through this dash-component-boilerplate.

Comment: Yes. You can put multiple react files inside the `src/lib/components` directory. Then inside `src/lib/index.js` you can import and export these components so each component is accessible through the module that is generated by `npm run build`.